# Getting method's local variable through another method

Tags: java, oop

How to get a value which declared and initialized in another method without using parameter in java?

```
public class Value {
    void method1()
    {
        int demo=10;
        System.out.println("methd 1"+demo);
    }
    void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("method 2"+demo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Value obj = new Value ();
        obj.method1();
        obj,method2();
    }
}
```

Here the variable demo is declared in method1 and assigned a value now I need to get the value of demo in method 2 is this possible without any parameter, global declaration, and no getter setter method?

Comment: `method2()` has no value for `demo`, as it isn't defined. In `main()`, you have `obj,method2()`, which should be `obj.method2()`

Comment: you should learn variable scope this is very basic.

Comment: @Rustam you shouldnt criticize people for trying to learn.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do it without the things you listed? What's your actual end goal here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Value {
    void method1()
    {
        int demo=10;
        System.out.println("methd 1"+demo);
    }
    void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("method 2");
        this.method1();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Value obj = new Value ();
        obj.method1();
        obj.method2();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Value {
int method1()
{
    int demo=10;
    System.out.println("methd 1"+demo);
    return demo;
}
void method2()
{        
    int demos = this.method1();
    System.out.println("method 2 "+demos);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Value obj = new Value ();
  //  obj.method1();
    obj.method2();
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible, because `demo` doesn't exist once `method1` has returned. It's a **local variable** within `method1`.

> ...without any parameter,global declaration, and no getter setter method?

That pretty much rules everything out, **if** by "global declaration" you mean making `demo` an instance field (which isn't a global, but I think that's what you meant).

But just for completeness, here's `demo` as an instance field:

```
public class Value {
    private int demo;

    void method1()
    {
        this.demo = 10;
        System.out.println("method 1" + this.demo);
    }
    void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("method 2" + this.demo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Value obj = new Value ();
        obj.method1();
        obj.method2();
    }
}
```

You're not *required* to use `this.` when accessing it, but doing so makes it clear it's an instance field, not a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
int demo
```

in method1 is just local to the function method1. I don't know what java compiles from such code, but you can be sure, that such a variable will simply go into a register when you use a compiler that creates bytecode for your processor. You just use this as a convenient name for a variable.

If you want to use the variable in other methods, you need to share this value as data member in `class Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Although local variables of methods are being discarded at compile time, you can get them if you compile with debug information `javac -g`. You can take advantage of the bytecode libraries ASM or BCEL. If you suspend your JVM by the debug agent you can also exploit a remote debugger API.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Value {
    int demo;
public int getDemo(){return demo;}
public void setDemo(int demo){this.demo=demo;}

    void method1() {
       // demo=10;
        System.out.println("methd 1"+demo);
    }

    void method2() {

System.out.println("method 2"+demo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Value obj = new Value ();
//set the value of demo using setter method        

obj.method1();
        obj.method2();
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but he didn't want getters & setters